# Coq: default values for vectors

Tags: coq

Let's say there is a vector of length $n$:

```
Require Import Vector.
Variable T:Type.
Variable n:nat.
Variable v:t T n.
```

"list" gives a function "nth" that demands a default result that is returned when the list is longer than the index requested. This is convenient, and the definition is readable.

Now vector uses a definition of nth (using Fin) that assures on type level that the requested Index is smaller than the length of the vector. Confusingly, it also uses a constructor "t", just like Vector. How can I define a function that behaves the same as nth for lists? The definition of nth for vector plainly appears as unreadable to me. Should I use "to_list"?

Was this built this way to keep the type small (in the memory sense)?

Comment: This seems to be a question for Coq support mailing lists, not a question about computer science.

Comment: @Raphael This question is borderline between language design (on-topic) and programming (off-topic, though we don't have a firm rule about writing constructive proofs, which isn't run-of-the-mill programming). I'm reopening it for now (to give people a chance at answering — I might do it myself); if we decide to close it here, we'll migrate to [so]. I've [raised the issue on meta](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/860/what-part-of-coq-default-values-for-vectors-is-on-topic).

Comment: @Gilles It was the last line that pushed me to off-topic; I'm sure there is a language-design issue somewhere in there.

Comment: What do you mean by “small in the memory sense”?

Comment: The data structure describing the type would be as long as the vector itself, when you naively implement a type that breaks down a natural number.

Comment: I think the question about "smallness" is the "t" as the type of Vectors. Your intuition is wrong here: the letter "t" is used to denote the "base" type of the module in question, here Vector. This comes from the OCaml tradition, where you want to write Vector.t instead of Vector.vector, or even worse ``open Vector`` and pollute your namespace.

Comment: This question already includes an answer. Of course you can use `to_list`. But, then, what's the point of using vectors? Vectors are used when we don't want to consider exception cases.